# How to create forms for foreign key django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Models,

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    website=models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    publication=models.ForeignKey(Publication)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self,*args,**kwagrs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.slug)
        super(Book,self).save(*args,**kwagrs)
```

I tried to make form for publication objects. Which is working fine. But I am ubnable to make form for Book object, as it haves publication as foreign key.

forms.py ,

```
class PublicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the publication name.")
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the address for publication.")
    website=forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the URL of publication.")
    class Meta:
        model = Publication
```

How can I create form for book object having publication as a foreign key.

**Update**

I have tried form for book object as,

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name.")
    author = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name of the autthor.")
    slug = forms.SlugField(help_text="Please enter the slug")
    publication = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                        queryset=Publication.objects.all()
                                        )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author','slug','publication')
```

But when I submit form it throws error below,

```
Cannot assign "[<Publication: C# in Depth>]": "Book.publication" must be a "Publication" instance.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are using `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, its giving a queryset of `Publication` in form, and you are using foreignkey relation in between `Book` and `Publication` models, so the modelform can't save `publication` because its not getting a `publication` object. So you can do like this to solve the issue:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name.")
    author = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name of the autthor.")
    slug = forms.SlugField(help_text="Please enter the slug")
    publication = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(x.id,x.name) for x in Publication.objects.all()]
         )

    def save(self, commit=True):
      instance = super().save(commit=False)
      pub = self.cleaned_data['publication']
      instance.publication = Publication.objects.get(pk=pub)
      instance.save(commit)
      return instance


    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author','slug')
```

Or you can use ModelMultipleChoiceField like this:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name.")
    author = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name of the autthor.")
    slug = forms.SlugField(help_text="Please enter the slug")
    publication = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                        queryset=Publication.objects.all()
                                        )
    def save(self, commit=True):
       instance = super().save(commit=False)
       pub = self.cleaned_data['publication']
       instance.publication = pub[0]
       instance.save(commit)
       return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author','slug')
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried second option I am getting error as `super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

Comment: Sorry, I gave the answer using python3. You should use it like:`instance = super(BookForm, self).save(commit=False)`

Comment: hijacked account. please delete this

Answer (score 1):

Take look into this [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

```
publication = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book.objects.all())
```

Comment: hijacked account. please delete this

Answer (score 0):

Try to link them in view. With save(commit=False) you create a Book object that waiting for to complete its data. When you complete book object, you can save it with all its foreign keys

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    bf = BookForm(request.POST)
    publication_id = request.POST.get('publication_id',0)
    if bf.is_valid():
        if publication_id:
            book = bf.save(commit=False)
            book.publication_id = publication_id
            book.save()
        else:
            # functional error.
    else:
        # functional  error.
```

Comment: hijacked account. please delete this